# mysql create trigger in init-file dosnt work

Tags: mysql

I have a problem to creating triggers at startup from mysql and i dont know why.@.@

A table is deleted, newly created and filled. Then triggers should be created.
The script ist really simple:

```
USE dbname;
DROP TABLE `tag2kw`;
CREATE TABLE `tag2kw` ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM `tag2kw_origin`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `sync_tag2kw_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `tag2kw` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        //std insert into tag2kw_origin
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It is strange that it works in the Gui and also via shell command.
But not if the script is executed as the mysql init-file.
The first part (delete and create) works there, but the triggers are not created.

Yes I can do the shell script in the Taskplaner, but I would like to have it directly in mysql.
Does anyone have any idea where the problem is?

[edit]
This insert inside the trigger is a standard insert. 
If I create the triggers via the shell, they also work as intended.
That's why I removed the insert for legibility. 
The insert:

```
INSERT INTO tag2kw_origin ( 
    tag2kw_id, lk2einl_id, datum, uhrzeit_von, uhrzeit_bis, mitarbeiter_id, mitarbeiter_id_2, raum_id, raum_id_2, raum_id_3, aktiv 
) VALUES ( 
    NEW.tag2kw_id, NEW.lk2einl_id, NEW.datum, NEW.uhrzeit_von, NEW.uhrzeit_bis, NEW.mitarbeiter_id, NEW.mitarbeiter_id_2, NEW.raum_id, NEW.raum_id_2, NEW.raum_id_3, NEW.aktiv 
);
```

**[edit & solved]** thy for the fast answers :D
If i remove the beginn + end after 'for each row' i dont need the delimiter and whithout the delimiter it works perfectly. :)
Now it looks so:

```
USE dbname;
DROP TABLE `tag2kw`;
CREATE TABLE `tag2kw` ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM `tag2kw_origin`;

CREATE TRIGGER `sync_tag2kw_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `tag2kw` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        //std insert into tag2kw_origin;

//create other trigger
```

Comment: 'insert into tag2kw_origin' - why and what? obviously //std insert into tag2kw_origin will not syntax but what does the real insert look like?

Comment: @P.Salmon This is a standard insert.
If I create the triggers via the shell, they also work as intended.
That's why I removed the insert for legibility.
Thats the insert:

INSERT INTO `tag2kw_origin` (
`tag2kw_id`, `lk2einl_id`, `datum`, `uhrzeit_von`, `uhrzeit_bis`, `mitarbeiter_id`, `mitarbeiter_id_2`, `raum_id`, `raum_id_2`, `raum_id_3`, `aktiv`
) VALUES (
NEW.tag2kw_id, NEW.lk2einl_id, NEW.datum, NEW.uhrzeit_von, NEW.uhrzeit_bis, NEW.mitarbeiter_id, NEW.mitarbeiter_id_2, NEW.raum_id, NEW.raum_id_2, NEW.raum_id_3, NEW.aktiv
);

Comment: Do ot post as a comment - edit the question.

Comment: If the trigger creating statement is sent, but the trigger is not created, then some error occures. Obtain and show the error message. PS. I think the problem is in `DELIMITER` reassign which is client command, not SQL statement.

Comment: But wher can i find the error. The mysql_error.log shows nothing related. :/
But it can be that the delimiter is the problem.
I changed the first part to use the delimiter and now this dont work too. _._
But the delimiter isnt a problem for the command line and the gui's. How they handle the delimiter problem?

Comment: @akina thanks for the hint, this was really the answer :D
If i remove beginn+end after 'for each row' i dont need the delimiter. And now it works.